# sum with combination

Tags: postgresql, sqlite, sum

I reproduce the table in image and result I expect.
So, I like sum for each item withe the sum of related item. But some item are null or join to himself.
I think some array can help me but I don't understand how to group result.
I am in sqlite, but I can make it in postgresql, if necessary.

[image: table]

Comment: *I reproduce the table in image and result I expect.* You should provide source data as textual CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO or a link to online fiddle, and desired output as formatted table.

Comment: Go to dbfiddle.uk and put in your table and data!

Answer (score 1):

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS ( SELECT id, cnt, rel_id
         FROM test
         WHERE rel_id IN (id, '')
       UNION ALL
         SELECT test.id, test.cnt + cte.cnt, test.rel_id
         FROM cte
         JOIN test ON cte.id = test.rel_id AND test.rel_id <> test.id )
SELECT * 
FROM cte
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(id FROM 2)::INT;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=4a1ba6b80f25c2af17a1308bfd3b975f

---

> the question says "But some item are null" so I assume the "blank" values are NULL in reality. Not everyone (or every tool) displays a `NULL` value as `(null)` – [a_horse_with_no_name](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1822/a-horse-with-no-name)

Well, if empty cell is NULL and not empty string, then

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS ( SELECT id, cnt, rel_id
         FROM test
         WHERE NULLIF(rel_id, id) IS NULL
       UNION ALL
         SELECT test.id, test.cnt + cte.cnt, test.rel_id
         FROM cte
         JOIN test ON cte.id = test.rel_id AND test.rel_id <> test.id )
SELECT * 
FROM cte
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(id FROM 2)::INT;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=d55d5086a773ea37ffb019e32cfbae4c